# DELETE triggers SQLITE_ERROR SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)

Tags: java, sqlite, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I don't understand why I am getting this error.. In my web application I have used many methods where I execute `insert`, `select`, `update` etc where all of them works correctly without errors... Now I want to implement a `delete` action. So, I have:

```
public void deleteBox(Label label) 
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Deleting box from BOXES");
        sq = "DELETE FROM BOXES WHERE product=? AND version=? AND productionD=? AND AA=?";

        try {       
            Class.forName(typeDB);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(path);    
            PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);

            stm.setString(1, label.getProduct());
            stm.setString(2, label.getVersion());
            stm.setString(3, label.getDateProduction());
            stm.setString(4, label.getPacketNumber());
            stm.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {             
            System.out.println("hereeee error:  " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        if (stm != null)
                    stm.close();  //<---
        if (c != null)
                    c.close();
        } 

    }
```

where `path` and `typeDB` are defined as:

```
private final String path = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\DB_LABELS\\labels.sqlite";
private final String typeDB= "org.sqlite.JDBC";
```

and in the start of the class:

```
private Connection c = null;
 PreparedStatement stm = null;
```

This method is called from the servlet here:

```
try{
     Label box = (Label) session.getAttribute("boxFound");

     action.deleteBox(box); //here I call the method

     //some other stuff here..
     action.addTransaction(box, "extract", timeStamp1, user.getId());
     old = action.searchQuantityOfPackage(box);

    }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
          System.err.println("Exception at extract. More: " + e);
}
```

When it is executed I get an error:

```
Deleting box from BOXES
Exception at extract. More: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)
```

and all the other commands aren't executed inside the `try`. I don't understand why is this happening. As I said in the begging I use the same setting for other sql actions so both `path` and `typeDB` must be defined correctly. If I delete `action.deleteBox(box);` no error is happening, so sth is happening in this method...

**ALSO**

I forgot to mention that the delete of the row in the table `BOXES` is happening despite the error!

I add also the ful stack trace

```
    Exception at extract. More: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.internalClose(CoreStatement.java:109)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.close(JDBC3Statement.java:35)
    at gr.products.labelInventory.ActionsDB.deleteBox(ActionsDB.java:557)
    at gr.products.labelInventory.Inventory.processRequest(Inventory.java:285)
    at gr.products.labelInventory.Inventory.doGet(Inventory.java:652)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at gr.products.labelInventory.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

this line `at gr.products.labelInventory.ActionsDB.deleteBox(ActionsDB.java:557)` points to the <-- i put in the code.

Comment: Instead of just printing the exception message, print the full stack trace. This will give you an indication as to which statement *exactly* caused the error. Add the stack trace to your question if you want further help.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ok I add it

Comment: Try replacing the `if (stm != null)` with `if (stm != null && ! stm.isClosed())`. I think (not sure) that your statement is already closed when you get to the `finally`.

Comment: I did and I got the same error.. I remove it although and I have no error now.. :/ ?

Comment: I print the `stm.isClosed()` and it is `false`

Comment: Anyway, if you are checking for null, you should also assign `stm = null` and `c = null` after you close, otherwise they may be not-null and not-closed. It may be that you are using multiple threads with this class.

Comment: I assign them in the start of the class.. I update the question also with this information..

Comment: Why are the statement and connection instance fields, and not variables local to the method. Very likely another request is running in parallel and has already closed the connection.

Comment: Yes exactly that was the problem!!!!! Post as it an answer to take the credits!